# Wordpress site loads in LAN but not from WAN, yet parent direction loads with both

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

-------------------------Solved-------------------------

See solution in comments section by @fubar.

**Goal:** Wordpress website set up on my Synology using Web Station Suite. Use free ddns from no-ip to make it accessible.

**Current State:** Site is accessible in LAN at http://192.168.1.157:888/wordpress/. But it is not accessible from WAN at http://tnz.ddns.name:888/wordpress/.

However, both http://192.168.1.157:888/index.html and http://tnz.ddns.name:888/index.html will load.

192.168.1.157:888 is the parent directory for the Web Station which would load 'index.html' in the image below:
[Web Station Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCZTX.png)

192.168.1.157:888/wordpress/ is obviously the directory of the Wordpress site, structure of the folder is shown below:
[directory of the Wordpress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3psY.png)

Below is the only relavant settings item I could find that seems relevant. 
[Wordpress Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ayfs.png)

**In summary**, everything would load except the wordpress folder and I highly suspect it's a settings issue with wordpress. Yet I failed at searching for people with similar situations.

**.htaccess file content:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**wp-config.php file content:**

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, and ABSPATH. You can find more information by visiting
 * {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing wp-config.php}
 * Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME','wordpressblog');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER','wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
/*keys are deleted here just to be safe on the web :P*/
define('AUTH_KEY',' '); 
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',' ');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',' ');
define('NONCE_KEY',' ');
define('AUTH_SALT',' ');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT',' ');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',' ');
define('NONCE_SALT',' ');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/language-selector/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/language-selector/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', 'en_En');
define('WP_LANG_DIR', '/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/language-selector/language-selector/languages');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "888") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
} else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
}

$virtual_host_file = file_get_contents("/etc/httpd/sites-enabled-user/httpd-vhost.conf-user");
if (preg_match('/ServerName '.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/', $virtual_host_file)) {
    define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL);
} else {
        define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL.'/wordpress');
}

if (!defined('SYNOWORDPRESS'))
    define('SYNOWORDPRESS', 'Synology Inc.');

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'syno-misc.php');
```

Comment: I haven't used WordPress for a number of years, but have you tried changing both WordPress URL settings to be the same? I'd try making them both: http://tnz.ddns.name:888/index.html

Comment: @fubar Thanks for your quick reply! As it is shown in the image, 'WordPress Address URL' is greyed out and not writtable. I'll have a search and see if there's any way I can change it :D Cheers

Comment: Ah okay. That might be a new change to WordPress. As I said, I'm a little out of touch. But nearly every instance I ever set up, both URLs were the same.

Comment: @fubar Apparently causes of this can be wp-config.php or the theme overwriting these values hence making them not editable. However, after checking, my wp-config.php doesn't define these values nor does my theme. I've also tried using a different theme but no luck. Then I tried to change that value in phpMyAdmin but there's no updates in the WordPress settings.

Comment: I redefined the URLs in the wp-config.php and forced them to be the same. However still no luck. Still, thank you for your time and help!!! Loving this community.

Comment: @fubar It turns out you were right! After I forced these two to be the same, I wasn't able to access it within the LAN network using a domain name (I still have access via 192.168.xx.xx), however I could access it outside LAN using the domain name! Really appreciate your help :D

Comment: Awesome. Glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ages old, but just to add the solution to the problem here:

In wp-config.php, comment out:

```
if ($_SERVER["HOST"] != "") {
    define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL);
} else {
    define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL.'/wordpress');
```

That makes both addresses accessible for editing in the gui.